# Distribute Size of elements inside div

Tags: html, css

I want to display the unit of the input next to it. 
I don't want the unit "g" to break into the next line when the size of the div changes. 
The input should use all remaining space inside the div, as long as this does not cause a line break.

```html
<div style="width:100px">
  <input type="number" />
  g
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use display:flex and surround internal elements with a div tag. More on flex you can find on Mother Google.

Hope this helps.

```html
<div style="width:100px;display:flex;">
    <div><input type="number" /></div>
    <div>g</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Easiest** way and cross-browser supported way is using **display** - **table** and **table-cell**

You can wrap **'g'** inside another `<div>`. Then you can get it in **side-by-side** irrespective of **width** by following CSS

```css
body > div {
  display: table;
}
body > div > * {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px">
  <input type="number" />
  <div>g</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.,

just give some room for the text to display

Change width of your div

```html
<div style="width:200px;">
  <input type="number" />
  g
</div>
```